# ReactJS IconButton not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, cross-browser, material-ui

The click function of `IconButton` from `Material UI` is not working in any version of `FireFox`. This is the code I am using:

```
<div className='floating-button visible-xs'>
  <IconButton touch={true} tooltipPosition="bottom-left">
    <Create className='floating-button-icon' onTouchTap={this.props.onProfileEdit}/>
  </IconButton>
</div>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? The code above is 100% working in `Chrome` and `Safari`.

Comment: try `onClick` instead of `onTouchTap`.

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6725

Comment: @MayankShukla @karthik I already changed it to `onClick` but still no luck. It's not working on my end. Do we have any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `onClick` prop instead of `onTouchTap` and apply it to `IconButton` component itself instead of to particular icon.

```
<div className='floating-button visible-xs'>
  <IconButton touch={true} tooltipPosition="bottom-left" onClick={this.props.onProfileEdit}>
    <Create className='floating-button-icon' />
  </IconButton>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks @falinsky. It worked for me. But by the way, it did not work on this one:
`<form onSubmit={(e)=>this._handleSubmit(e)}>
            <FlatButton label="Choose an Image" labelPosition="before" onChange={(e)=>this._handleImageChange(e)}>
              <input type="file" style={styles.imageInput}/>
            </FlatButton>
          </form>`

Comment: @zuma You can see examples of using IconButton working in pair with input or type `file`: https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#contained-buttons

Comment: I fixed the `FlatButton` issue above by adding `containerElement='image'`. 
`<form onSubmit={(e)=>this._handleSubmit(e)}>
            <FlatButton containerElement='image' label="Choose an Image" labelPosition="before" onChange={(e)=>this._handleImageChange(e)}>
              <input type="file" style={styles.imageInput}/>
            </FlatButton>
          </form>`